# ScintillaNET Auto-Completion List Issue

Tags: c#, wpf, scintilla

I am using the `ScintillaNET` in `WPF/C#` via the `WindowsFormsHost`. However, it seems that the control is having an auto-completion problem. I am using a `List<string>` to hold text to show in the auto-complete drop-down. The variable `lang` is my `List<string>` and `editor` is my `ScintillaNET` editor:

```
lang.Add("fprintf");
lang.Add("fscanf");
lang.Add("printf");
lang.Add("scanf");
lang.Add("snprintf");

lang.Add("remove");
lang.Add("rename");
lang.Add("tmpfile");
lang.Add("tmpnam");

lang.Add("fclose");
lang.Add("fflush");
lang.Add("fopen");
lang.Add("freopen");
lang.Add("setbuf");
lang.Add("setvbuf");

editor.AutoComplete.List = lang;
```

If I typed `printf` for example, the drop-down goes to the word `printf`. However, if I select a word added later in the list, like `fopen`, the same effect (as with `printf`) does not happen. The drop-down acts as though the word was not there.

But, the word has been correctly added to the drop-down (as when I scroll down the list), I see `fopen` there.

Why is the auto-complete box not going to `fopen` when I typed it, but it goes `printf` when I typed `printf` and how can I solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Scintilla likes the list in sorted order. Try doing a

```
lang.Sort();
editor.AutoComplete.List = lang;
```

That should do the trick for you.

The underlying Scintilla editor has an Autosort feature, but this is not exposed to the .NET version as far as I can see.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the preferred solution regarding better performance is [Torgrim Brochmann'a answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18899554/463828), but you can also make Scintilla do the sort for you:

```
editor.AutoCOrder = Order.PerformSort;
```

You only need to set this once and the editor will sort the list for you everytime.